# add css content text in 'empty' divs

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-content

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xanld/3yh28/

```
div:before {
    content: 'This div is empty';
}
div:empty {
    background:red;
}
```

I'd like to add css content to empty divs only. I can either use the :empty selector, but I need to use the :before selector in order to add content. Is it possible to use both?

Thanks.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes, you can use both - see updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3yh28/1/

```
div:empty:before {
   content: 'This div is empty';
}
```

Make sure it's `:empty:before` (**not `:before:empty`**), because you want to apply the pseudo-element `:before` on the element that matches `div:empty`.

By the way, [`:empty` is CSS3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3aempty) and not supported on old browsers (such as IE8, or about 40% of the browser market share)

Comment: Damnit. That's so simple, I thought I'd tried it. Infact what I think I'd tried was div:before:empty and not div:empty:before, and then just assumed that this syntax was invalid. Thanks :)

Comment: That **is** confusing. Updated the answer to warn about the order.